# openssl_decrypt(): Setting tag for AEAD cipher decryption failed

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, php-openssl

i hope you all doing great.

I am working on **encryption/decryption** using **openssl** extension. When i code like below, it works fine even if i don't use **bin2hex()**. Please note that **$tag** has static value for every user, it will never changed unlike **$iv** and **$key**.

```
$plaintext = 'password';
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
$tag = 'tqjFo+ChP8UB2gHkG9F5Vw==';
echo '<pre>';       

    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    
    $iv = bin2hex($iv);
    $key = bin2hex($key);

    $encrypted = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv,$tag));
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin(($encrypted)), $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv,$tag);
    echo 'key='.$key. "\n";
    echo 'iv='.$iv. "\n";
    echo 'plaintext='.$plaintext. "\n";
    echo 'encrypted to: '.$encrypted. "\n";
    echo 'decrypted to: '.$decrypted. "\n\n";


echo '</pre>';
```

> The problem is when i have to store **$iv**,**$key** and
> **$encrypted** in database(mySql) and use them for later decryption.

**First let me show you how i am doing this**

> Database (i am not sure about field type either it should be string,binary etc)

[image]

> This function encrypt password and store $iv,$key and $encryptedData
> into database

```
public function createOpenSSL(Request $req){
    $plaintext = $req->password;
    $cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
    $tag = "tqjFo+ChP8UB2gHkG9F5Vw==";
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $iv = bin2hex($iv);
    $key = bin2hex($key);
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv,$tag);
    $user = new openssl();
    $user->password = $encrypted;
    $user->ukey = $key;
    $user->iv =$iv;
    $user->save();

}
```

> This function will find user matching "id" and decrypt the
> password(**but unfortunately it's not working**)

```
public function showOpenSSL(Request $req){
    $user = openssl::findorFail($req->id);
    $cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
    $tag = "tqjFo+ChP8UB2gHkG9F5Vw==";
    $key = hex2bin($user->ukey);
    $iv = hex2bin($user->iv);
    $encrypted = $req->password;
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $cipher, $key, $options=0,$iv,$tag);  
}
```

When the above function is executed, "openssl_decrypt(): Setting tag for AEAD cipher decryption failed" error is occur. I have tried my best for last 2 days but could not find nothing. Please tell me where i am doing wrong. Please also guide me about database field type best for storing **$iv**, **$key** and **$encrypted**.

Comment: The AEAD tag is _not_ something that _you_ set, it's computed during the encryption process and is more or less a checksum produced by the algo itself. It will be different for _every_ encryption operation. Basically you need to save the tag as well. Most schemes just pack the IV, tag, and ciphertext into a single string as they will all always be unique.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67107/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-authentication-tag-in-aead-encryption-schemes

Comment: @Sammitch means TAG will be produced by openssl_encryption()??

Comment: Yes. It is passed by reference into [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) and the tag is written to it. Try checking the value before and after the operation.

Comment: Also if you're storing the encryption key right next to the ciphertext in the DB you might as well be storing it in plaintext. [Hashing your passwords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) is far simpler to accomplish securely.

Comment: @Sammitch You are right, tag is computed by openssl itself.

Comment: @Sammitch yes i can do hashing but using open_ssl is customer requirement. Please guide me about column input type. Should i save data in hexadecimal form or binary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221895/discussion-between-noman-marwat-and-sammitch).